# How to query postgis database using jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, spatial, hibernate-spatial

I want to mix jpa with spatial queries. I'm using hibernate-spatial 1.1.1 an hib 3.6.x. There is already a solution here http://www.hibernatespatial.org/pipermail/hibernatespatial-users/2008-May/000200.html  but i do not know if it is still valid, 2008  was ages ago. And the hibernate-spatial that does what i want is for version 4 of hibernate-spa.

Comment: hib-spa 1.1.1 was released in 2011 but still that's a pretty long time

Comment: I've used "normal" Hibernate to query PostGIS database. You could create a Native Query calling the PostGIS functions and return the query result as an entity (by @SqlResultSetMapping). I think it's a good way to do that.